# window message doesn't work on capacitor ios after deployment to Testflight

Tags: ios, angular, iframe, testflight, capacitor

I have a ionic5 + capacitor app built using Angular. On a particular page in the app i need the user to fill in some data into the iframe and submit it. I used window.postMessage and message event for communication with the iframe. This works fine on chrome, firefox, safari and android. The issue only lies with the iOS.

Issue:

Once the app has been deployed to the testflight and upon using the app i am able to post message to the iframe but the window doesnt trigger 'message' event listener.

while debugging the app i noticed that the origin changes from `http://localhost` to `capacitor://localhost` once deployed. I also checked the server response headers on submiting the iframe and it has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Error logs when the package app is run

```
2021-05-10 14:22:14.518064+1000 App[9997:2740595] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x105d0bff0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x282854900>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
```

```
2021-05-10 14:22:14.518205+1000 App[9997:2740595] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x105d0bff0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x282854900>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
```

I have also tried the @Host and @Hostlistener directives but they dont work once deployed.

App template.html

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <iframe
    id="i-frame"
    [src]="testUrl | safeUrl"
    frameborder="0"
    width="100%"
    scrolling="no"
  ></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

App component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public modalController: ModalController, public zone: NgZone) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    window.addEventListener('message', (e) => this.zone.run(() => this.receiveMessage(e)));
  }

  receiveMessage(e) {
    if (e.origin === window.location.origin || !e.data) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      const response = JSON.parse(e.data);
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  saveData(event: Event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const frameById = document.getElementById('i-frame');
    const childFrame = frameById['contentWindow'] || frameById['contentDocument'];
    childFrame.postMessage({ actionType: 'create' }, this.testUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: try this "declare let window:any;" before @comonent

Comment: @ravi-ashara sorry for replying late. I tried it, it throws error.


`⚡️  [error] - ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'window.addEventListener')
drainMicroTaskQueue@capacitor://localhost/polyfills-es2015.js:3675:46
promiseReactionJob@[native code]
`